# Hello. i try to click all element of div but it now works

Tags: javascript, svg

I try clicking on all divs but event works for last divs. how to call function for each div ?
i want which div has been clicked the javascript call function for this.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUhjZ.jpg]

```
<svg height="300" width="300" class="centerization">
    <style>
        .es{
            margin-top: 30px;
        }
        .es:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es"> 
    </rect>
    <rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
    x="100"></rect>
    <rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
    x="200"></rect>
    <rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
    y="100"></rect>
    <rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
    y="100" x="100"></rect>
    <rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
    y="100" x="200"></rect>
    <rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
    y="200"></rect>
    <rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
    y="200" x="100"></rect>
    <rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
    y="200" x="200"></rect>
</svg>

var svg = document.getElementsByClassName("es");
for (var property in svg) {
    svg[property].addEventListener("click",function(){
        alert("clicked"+svg[property]);
    });
};
```

Comment: your js is not under `<script>` tag. I am afraid if that is even working in first place

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I think it's just a matter of SO post formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getElementsBy* methods return HTMLCollections, which can be difficult to work with. Consider using querySelectorAll instead, which returns a static NodeList - unlike an HTMLCollection, it can be iterated over directly, it won't change while it's being iterated over, and it's much more flexible.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.es')
  .forEach((es) => {
    es.addEventListener('click', () => alert('clicked ' + es.outerHTML));
  });
```

```css
.es {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.es:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es">
</rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" x="100"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" x="200"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" y="100"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" y="100" x="100"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" y="100" x="200"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" y="200"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" y="200" x="100"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" y="200" x="200"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `click` event to each element of the `svg` array. You can use the simple `for` loop for this:

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByClassName("es");
for(var i=0; i<svg.length; i++) {
   svg[i].addEventListener("click",function(){
       alert("clicked");
   });
};
```

```css
.es{
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.es:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<svg>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es"> 
</rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
x="100"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
x="200"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
y="100"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
y="100" x="100"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
y="100" x="200"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
y="200"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
y="200" x="100"></rect>
<rect height="40" width="80" fill="blue" rx="5" ry="5" class="es" 
y="200" x="200"></rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: @გენომუმლაძე click on all boxes, you get alert

Comment: You can't understand. The result is for only last DIV

Comment: @გენომუმლაძე read this `I try clicking on all divs but event works for last divs. how to call function for each div ?` you will know who does not understand. You see this `... call function for each div`?